# Got The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have looked at other answers to this question, but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Generally, there are two urls.py - one in my `account` folder, and another one in my `bookmarks` folder which are in the root folder - `bookmarks`.

When I try to create a superuser, I get this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'account.urls' from '/Users/aleksanderjess/Documents/PacktPub/Django/bookmarks/account/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I have absolutely no clue why. The imports look legit and all.

Here are two `urls.py`

`account/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from . import views

urls = [
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

and then there's the one in bookmarks, which looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
]
```

Comment: It's `urlpatterns`, not `urls`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One defines the list of url patterns in a variable named `urlpatterns`, *not* <s>`urls`</s>, as is specified in the [documentation on URL dispatching [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

> (...)
>
> Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable **`urlpatterns`**. This should be a Python list of `django.urls.path()` and/or `django.urls.re_path()` instances.
>
> (...)

So the system thus raises an error that you appear to have forgotton something. You can fix it by renaming `urls` to `urlpatterns`:

```
# account/urls.py

from django.contrib.auth import views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 5):

If your urls.py imports a class-based view that uses `reverse()`, you will get this error; using `reverse_lazy()` will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `ImproperlyConfigured` error due to the fact that I was using the same virtual environment for two projects, executed command

> pip install -r requirements.txt

for these two projects. I created new virtual environment and error has gone.